# 403 permission error when attempting to create a channel with discord.py

Tags: discord.py

My code:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=discord.Intents.all())

    guild_id = 1111111111111
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    await guild.create_text_channel('test')
```

When I execute the above I get the error:

```
   await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/meUser/Code/run.py", line 40, in on_message
    await guild.create_text_channel('test')
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Under OAuth I have the permissions set as administrator for bot.
I did this after I setup my server thou.  I'm not sure if it updates or if I have to reset the token.

[image]

Comment: Just choosing its permissions there will not give your bot the permissions on servers it's already in; either give it permissions by role or re-invite it with the new permissions.

Comment: Can you explain by role? Which would I need to give it to access the channels @Catgal

Answer (score 0):

My error was updating the current details on the discord developer portal with out updating the token.  The token needed to be updated for it to have the correct scopes.  Simply updating the scope did not work.